# streamreader to read xml file and then file.move to move the xml file - c#

Tags: c#

Using Jon Skeet's code

```
static IEnumerable<XElement> SimpleStreamAxis(string inputUrl,
                                              string elementName)
{
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
  {
    reader.MoveToContent();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      {
        if (reader.Name == elementName)
        {
          XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
          if (el != null)
          {
            yield return el;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

He posted on this thread:
[Jon Skeet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c)

After I read the data, I use File.Move(currentDest,newDest) and I keep getting that the file is currently in use by another process. I have checked to see that there is no editor that has the file open or even browser. In addition I get part of the path could not be found

Does the yield within the using not close the reader ? do i have to close it explicitly?

File Move code

```
File.Move(Path.Combine(InPath, "test.xml"), Path.Combine(OutPath, "test.xml"));
```

EDIT:
It looks like the yield within the using streamreader does not close the file. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: `using` should invoke Dispose(), which should close the stream...

Comment: Have you tried a pure Linq to Xml solution or is your xml file too large to use the DOM approach?

Comment: You should post a answer to your own question so it wont keep showing up on the front page as unanswered.

Comment: @Scott, I do not qualify to answer my own ?

Comment: I have answered my own question before. You found what was wrong and as long as you write it up as an answer then yes:-) It also stops others from opening the post and reading everything just to find you solved it(as part of the question).

Comment: @all: what i thought was the solution isn't. the yield statement used above does not close the file as file.move operation now reports that the file is in use by another process.

Comment: That's how yield works...see SO question referenced in my answer update.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly closing the reader before exiting the `using` block?

**Update**
When you use yield, it doesn't actually do anything until you enumerate the IEnumerable. This is why you're having issues with the file staying open.

See this SO question: [yield return statement inside a using() { } block Disposes before executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539114/yield-return-statement-inside-a-using-block-disposes-before-executing)

You're probably going to have to create an IEnumerable, populate it, close your stream, then return the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a pure Linq to Xml solution you can do:

```
static IEnumerable<XElement> SimpleStreamAxis(string filePathAndName, string elementName)
  {
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePathAndName);

     IEnumerable<XElement> results = from n in doc.Descendants(elementName) 
                   select n; 
     //Do more stuff with the results as needed...

     doc.Save(filePathAndName); //Note you can change the location by supplying a different path

     return results;
  }
```