# Strange execution order when using nested method, yield return and using in combination

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using, yield-return

I'm unable to understand why `Program.Fetch1` and `Program.Fetch2` do not result in the exact same execution order. The only difference is that `Program.Fetch1` is calling `Program.Fetch` to do the actual fetch operation.

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> Fetch1()
    {
        using (Context c = new Context())
        {
            return Fetch(c);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Fetch(Context c)
    {
        foreach (int i in c.Fetch())
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Fetch2()
    {
        using (Context c = new Context())
        {
            foreach (int i in c.Fetch())
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fetch1:");
        foreach (int i in Fetch1())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Fetch2:");
        foreach (int i in Fetch2())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}


class Context : IDisposable
{

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Context.Dispose");
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Fetch()
    {
        return new int[] { 1, 2 };
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Fetch1:
Context.Dispose
1
2
Fetch2:
1
2
Context.Dispose
```

My only guess is that `Context.Dispose` is called first in `Program.Fetch1` because the scope of the using declaration was already left. But this is true for `Program.Fetch1` as well. So why do those method behave differently?

**Update:** My question is a duplicate of [yield return statement inside a using() { } block Disposes before executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539114/yield-return-statement-inside-a-using-block-disposes-before-executing)

Comment: Have you examined IL, generated for this code?

Comment: @Alex Voskresenskiy No, I did not. However I never did IL examination before - so I would have to find out how to do so first.

Comment: @Martin IL for yield/return is horrible, I wouldn't bother. You could try decompiling using ILSpy to see the state machine in C#.

Answer (score 6):

That's because those options are actually different:

- `Fetch` and `Fetch2`, using `yield`, create a state machine to be able to return an unmaterialized `IEnumerable`.
- In `Fetch1` you are simply calling `Fetch` and returning the generated state machine and disposing of the context without waiting for that `IEnumerable` to actually be materialized.

Basically, the difference is that in `Fetch2` you have a layer of deferred execution (using `yield`) while in `Fetch1` you don't, which means the using scope ends immediately when you return.

Comment: @I3arnonv I think you mixed something up: `Program.Fetch2` does not add another layer - `Program.Fetch2` is only calling `Context.Fetch`

Comment: @Martin true, I mixed `Context.Fetch` and `Program.Fetch`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Fetch` method returns an `IEnumerable`. When this is returned, your using block disposes the context. However, an IEnumerable is only the *promise* of execution. It *will* execute. When you enumerate it. This is known as [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx).

So when you actually enumerate it with your foreach, the enumeration will take place and the code of `Fetch` will actually execute. In a real program you would get errors because your context was already disposed.